# angularfie2 version 5 Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm using the angularfire2 version 5 and i'm getting the following error:

> Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type Observable < any [] >.

**This is my code:**

```
  exercisesList$: Observable <any[]>;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.exercisesList$ = this.workoutProvider.getExercises();
  }
```

*getExercises()*

```
 getExercises(){
    return this.db.list(`Exercises/${localStorage.getItem('workoutName')}`).valueChanges();
  }
```

*HTML*

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let exercise of exercisesList$ | async">{{exercise.name}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

*Screenshot*

[image]

Any one can explain what is the type of valueChanges and how can i solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently an open issue regarding this:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1299

You have two ways of solving it:

- Following transpiler tips, you can simply change the `exercisesList$` type to `Observable <{}[]>`
- Cast the return type:

`this.exercisesList$ = this.workoutProvider.getExercises() as Observable<any[]>`
`this.exercisesList$ = (Observable<any[]>) this.workoutProvider.getExercises()`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, i tried the first one i got the following `error:Type 'Observable<{}[]>' cannot be converted to type 'Observable<any[]>'.`

Comment: I retried to become:`this.exercisesList$ = this.workoutProvider.getExercises().valueChanges() as Observable <any[]>` and i leave the `this.exercicesList$` type as empty. and it work for me,, i don't now if it is the best practice because we should put type to `this.exercices`.